# Downloading and running a jar file

Tags: bash, jar, clojure

I'm trying to download a compiler for a language called Clojure.

I entered this into the command line:

```
java -jar compiler.jar
```

which should put me in interactive mode, but instead I just get a blank line. I'm thinking this has something to do with the version of Java I have installed (1.6_0.45). I'm using a Mac, version 10.8.3.

Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: is this about google-closure? then you should add the corresponding tag

Comment: blank line and waiting for input or blank line and back to command prompt?

Comment: This is a perfetly reasonable question. the answer is download Leiningen. @user829755 : no it is about the Clojure language

Answer (score 2):

Java 6 should be OK. Run

```
java -cp clojure-1.4.0.jar clojure.main
```

Read [Getting Started](http://clojure.org/getting_started)